# WM_NCCALCSIZE after Maximize, Minimize then Maximize from taskbar?

Tags: winapi, message, titlebar

I am developing a form with custom painting and sizing of the non client area. I am handling all of the appropriate NC window messages and everything is working great except for a certain sequence of actions. If the form is maximized, minimized and then click the task bar to maximize again, I do not receive a WM_NCCALCSIZE message. I receive the message when the form is maximized and minimized but not when maximized from the taskbar. My problem is that I am calculating the title bar rectangle when receiving the WM_NCCALCSIZE message, so when I redraw after this sequence, my title bar rectangle is the size of the task bar window of the minimized form. There are several places I could put in a hack to recalculate the title bar rectangle when painting, etc, but I'd prefer to find the intended method for calculating the non client area in this situation. Anyone know how or when I am supposed to recalculate the non client area?

Comment: No repro.  When you maximize, then minimize then click the taskbar button then it returns to maximized state.  How do you get it restored from the taskbar button?